# how to set stop criteria for a mysql cursor which iterates over all rows in a table, properly?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

I'm learning mysql cursor.

The following is a mysql procedure, I actually want to loop over all rows in table A, and  'select' something related in table B for each A's row.

Now the problem is this while loop breaks when the inner 'select' returns an empty set, that's obviously not the behavior i expected. (I want it to loop over all rows of A ! when the current row has nothing related in B, then move on to the next one! )

I've learned that the stop criteria for a cursor shall be something like `DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET stop=1;` and I also know that's the cause for the problem.

But what's the conventional work around for this situation?

```
create procedure SOME_PROC () 
BEGIN
    DECLARE temp_id int; 
    DECLARE cursor_id CURSOR FOR select id from A;
    DECLARE stop int default 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET stop=1; 
    OPEN cursor_id;
        FETCH cursor_id INTO temp_id;
        while stop <> 1 do
            select B.x from B where B.id = cursor_id;
            FETCH cursor_id INTO temp_id;
        end while;
    CLOSE cursor_id; 
END
```

Comment: Try this: `DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;` and then `REPEAT ... UNTIL done END REPEAT;`

Comment: will there be a difference between 'FOR NOT FOUND' and 'FOR SQLSTATE '02000''?

Comment: Well you can maybe optimize the `DECLARE cursor_id` query with something like `SELECT id FROM A WHERE ...` so that you will only get the results needed and then have a "clean" `HANDLER`.

Comment: this may help solve this specific problem, but I actually want to ask -- if there is an inner select, which could throw NOT FOUND exception, inside a curseor loop, how to set the stop criteria for the cursor?

Comment: Is this too specific ?

Answer (score 1):

Work Around: Use put SELECT ... INTO that may return no rows into a separate BEGIN ... END block with its own CONTINUE handler for NOT FOUND as a workaround.